# JSON PHP Join multimensional Array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json

I try to get data from my mysql database via php. I want to use json because it is very nice to handle in our android app.

I try the following:
We have three Datatables:

```
User:
-id
-name

REF_Interests
-ref_interests_id
-interestName

User_Ref_Interests
-id
-userid
-ref_interests_id
```

We create several users and interests like "swimming" with the ref_interests_id = 1 (e.g.)

How is it possible to get only one Row for each user with an array which holds the interests like this:

```
User:
-id
-name
-interests:
  --interest
    ---ref_interest_id
    ---interestName
  --interest
    ---ref_interest_id
    ---interestName
  --...
    ---...
    ---...
```

I join the tables which returns 4 rows for one user if this user has 4 interests. this is very uncomfortable to handle i think. So is there a better way than my actual solution?

Thank you thousand times!

Comment: Did you try encoding your array to jason using php function  json_encode()?

Comment: Yes Iam encoding it. But my SQL-Query returns multiple lines for each interest a user has

Comment: For a user once you get the resultset with multiple lines, run a foreach loop on the result set and capture the values in a array, and encode it to json then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't do it in one MySQL query.

I can suggest 2 solutions:

1. Run 2 queries: get users and get interests (use IN SQL operator). And then mix it all into one array. It will be very fast solution (because only 2 queries you will have). But you must write some PHP code
2. Run multiple queries: get all users and for each user get it interests. It will be slow but code will more simplest. This solution can be used in pagination case (LIMIT < 100).

I hope it will help.

**EDIT 2:**

First two queries way. It get only needed data from DB:

```
<?
$pdo  = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=tesst', 'root', '');

// add your conditions into WHERE section
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM User WHERE 1=1');
$stmt->execute();
$rawUsers = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$userIds = array();
$users   = array();
foreach ($rawUsers as $user) {
    $userIds[] = (int)$user['id'];
    $users[$user['id']] = $user;
    $users[$user['id']]['interests'] = array();
}

$stmt = $pdo->prepare('
    SELECT *
        FROM User_Ref_Interests
            JOIN REF_Interests
            ON REF_Interests.ref_interests_id = User_Ref_Interests.ref_interests_id
    WHERE User_Ref_Interests.userid IN ('.implode(',', $userIds).')
');
$stmt->execute();
$interests = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

foreach ($interests as $interest) {
    $users[$interest['userid']]['interests'][] = array('ref_interest_id' => $interest['ref_interests_id'], 'interestName' => $interest['interestName']);
}

echo '<pre>';
echo json_encode($users, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
echo '</pre>';
```

Output will be:

```
{
    "1": {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "u1",
        "interests": [
            {
                "ref_interest_id": "1",
                "interestName": "i1"
            },
            {
                "ref_interest_id": "2",
                "interestName": "u2"
            },
            {
                "ref_interest_id": "3",
                "interestName": "i3"
            }
        ]
    },
    "2": {
        "id": "4",
        "name": "u4",
        "interests": []
    }
}
```

Comment: the solution 1 sounds interesting. Could you help me a bit with some Code? Iam new to Mysql and PHP and do not really know what to search at google :/

Comment: Nice Answer, thank you. But i do not get it to work. I wrote echo "x" after each line and end up at this point:
foreach ($rawUsers as $user) {
}
even if i remove the code from this foreach there is no echo output after this foreach. May you help me again please?

Comment: @BenjaminWolf please add `error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');` into start of file PHP and run it again. It must show you PHP errors.

Comment: @BenjaminWolf also please tell me - what PHP version you're using?

Comment: I wrote a new answer because of the long code. Please have a look at the new answer. There are no errors shown.
EDIT: the version is 5.3.29. oh no. Do you have any references or codes for this version?

Comment: @BenjaminWolf i updated answer, removed other solution and fix it for your PHP version.

Comment: great work! It works if i remove "JSON_PRETTY_PRINT". Do I not remove the line, there will not be any output.
Maybe you have an idea why the Interest with the id 6 is null in the output? if i call the given sql statements in phpmyadmin there the interestsName appears as "Fußball". Could "ß" be a problem for json?

thousand times thank you @stepozer

Comment: @BenjaminWolf about `ß` - you must check table encoding. Because json_encode working only with `utf-8` encoding. If you will dump your table structure in PHPMyadmin and attach it into question i can say more info.

Comment: @BenjaminWolf sorry about `JSON_PRETTY_PRINT` - it was added only in PHP 5.4 and i forgot about it... (http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php#refsect1-function.json-encode-changelog)

Answer (score 0):

I change the Code to my needs like this, but it does not show any error when i call it in google chrome.

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
 ini_set('display_errors', '1');
//
// NOTE: this code for PHP 5.4 and greater (because i use new array syntax)
//
echo "0";

$pdo  = new PDO('mysql:host=servername;dbname=dbname', 'name', 'pw');
echo "1";
// add your conditions into WHERE section
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM user WHERE 1=1');
$stmt->execute();
$rawUsers = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
echo "2";
$userIds = [];
$users   = [];
foreach ($rawUsers as $user) {
    $userIds[] = (int)$user['id'];
    $users[$user['id']] = $user;
    $users[$user['id']]['interests'] = [];
}
echo "3";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('
    SELECT *
        FROM zuordnunguserinteressen
            JOIN interessen
            ON interessen.id = zuordnunguserinteressen.InteressenID
    WHERE zuordnunguserinteressen.UserID IN ('.implode(',', $userIds).')
');
echo "4";
$stmt->execute();
$interests = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
echo "2";
foreach ($interests as $interest) {
    $users[$interest['userid']]['interests'][] = ['InteressenID' => $interest['InteressenID'], 'Interesse' => $interest['Interesse']];
}

echo '<pre>';
echo json_encode($users, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
echo '</pre>';

?>
```